# Cannot read property during Mounted hook -- how to set up?

Tags: vue.js, node-modules, vue-cli-3

I am using the `mounted` hook to load a function called `.replaceIMG()` during page load, but I get the following error in console:

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceIMG' of undefined"
```

Here's my Single file component .vue template:

First, I imported a node module package called `UTIF.js` (this plugin allows browsers to render TIF files in browser!) like so:

```
const UTIF = require('utif/UTIF');
```

Then, in the Vue instance I have:

```
  mounted: function() {
    this.UTIF.replaceIMG();
  }
```

The `<template>` section contains this:

```
<div v-for='(image,index) in images' :key='index'>
            <a :href='imageLink + image.Graphic'>
                <img :src='imageLink + image.Graphic'>
            </a>
</div>
```

Full code here: https://gist.github.com/dosstx/5dbe76220a3126cb84f7ed12c610015c

Did I not require the package correctly into my VUE template? Thank you.

Comment: what happens if you remove 'this.' and just do `UTIF.replaceIMG()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove `this` from

```
mounted: function() {
    this.UTIF.replaceIMG();
}
```

to

```
mounted: function() {
    UTIF.replaceIMG();
}
```